# Ocultar Dialogo Android de la llamada USSD

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Actualmente tengo una aplicación donde estoy realizando llamadas USSD ,el cual genera una ventana de tipo dialogo propia del sistema mostrando las opciones ,

Lo que me gustaria es poder ocultarla , eliminarla

```
    public class USSDService extends AccessibilityService {
 String TAG="USSDService";
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
   //In my mobile the class name has been looks like this.
        if (event.getClassName().equals("com.mediatek.phone.UssdAlertActivity")) {
 //Method performGlobalAction (GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK) requires Android     
  //  4.1+
            performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {


    }
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
      Log.v(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
        info.packageNames = new String[]
                {"com.android.phone"};
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        setServiceInfo(info);
 }

}
```

In Manifest add the following things:

```
<service 
  android:name=".USSDService"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
</intent-filter>
```

Intente tambien realizar

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        this.keepFocus = true;
    }

    if (! hasFocus && this.keepFocus) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        am.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME );
    }
}
```

todos intentos fallidos

mi clase donde invoco a la llamada USSD es la siguiente

```
    public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 123;
    private boolean keepFocus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    }

    /*
     Metodo para iniciar seccion en la aplicacion
    */
    public void GoToLogin(View view) {
/*
        TextView txtPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPasswordLogin);
        String pass = txtPass.getText().toString();
        if (pass.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debe ingresar la contraseña ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (pass.length() > 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpdateSecretQuestions.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
*/


        String USSD = Uri.encode("*") + "611" + Uri.encode("#");
        requestUSSD(USSD);

        Globals.getTEXT();
        Globals.getTEXT();
    }

    private void dailNumber(String s) {
        String USSD = Uri.encode("*") + "611" + Uri.encode("#");
        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + USSD)));
    }


    private void requestUSSD(String USSD){

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
            return;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { //API >= 26
            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            manager.sendUssdRequest(USSD, new TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveUssdResponse(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, CharSequence response) {
                    super.onReceiveUssdResponse(telephonyManager, request, response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceiveUssdResponse()" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, int failureCode) {
                    super.onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(telephonyManager, request, failureCode);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceiveUssdResponseFailed()" + request, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Handler());
        }else{      //API < 26
            startService(new Intent(this, XXXX.class));
            dailNumber("*611#");
        }

    }
    //Detecta si los permisos fueron concedidos (android 6.0+)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE : {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // PERMISO CONCEDIDO!
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se tienen permisos CALL_PHONE!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

cualquier ayuda de como ocultar el dialogo de la llamada USSD , o como ocultar los poputs del sistema android , se agradece

Comment: El dialogo te refieres al de la llamada al código USSD. Si esto es así ese dialogo lo crea el sistema operativo, dudo que exista una forma usando el SDK de android para evitarlo ya que se genera al abrir la ventana de marcación.

Comment: si a ese mismo me referia , mm no me alientas mucho pero bueno seguire investigando si doy de alguna forma paso a dejar el conocimiento

Comment: Hola bruno, .con respecto al diálogo que se genera al llamar el USSD creo que sería complicado pero encontre esta respuesta, se supone que esto funciono para esconder el diálogo: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057625/prevent-ussd-dialog-and-read-ussd-response

Comment: Gracias Jorge , la verdad ya vi esta pregunta ayer y hoy lo volvi  a intentar por si me habia equivocado pero tampoco , creo que ya revise todas las preguntas de ES y de ingles , con respecto a ussd pero bueno gracias Jorge que tengas un buen dia !

Comment: ah ok luego me dices si funciona, igualmente buen día!